# Excel does not forget about my rows, after I deleted Them

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The Problem is kinda hard to explain for me, bc english isn't my native language. But I will try my best.

I programmed a macro which moves a table from my excel worksheet into an word Document. Which works great so far.

But after the Word Document is saved and closed I want to remove the transfered Data, which is still in Excel, from my Worksheet.

For Example:
My First Table has 10 Rows. All Ten Rows are transfered into the Word File.
My Programm deletes the Contents of all the cells in Excel.
I run the Programm again but this time with only 5 Rows in the table.
Now the Program seems to think that there are still 10 Lines and attatches 5 empty rows at the end     of the 5 filled ones.

[image: This is what it looks like when I Add 4 Lines with content]

This is how the Programms chooses which rows to copy. Normally it should stop at the first empty row.

```
    With myWorkSheet
        .Range("A2:D" & .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row).Copy
    End With
```

This is How I delete The Rows in my Excel Sheet Afterwards

```
    With myWorkSheet
        .Range("A2:D" & .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row).ClearContents
    End With
```

Comment: A row that has been used is indeed remembered as a used row. If you want to make Excel forget about them, you need to actually `Delete` them rather than `ClearContents`. Alternatively, switch to other methods of determining where your list stops.

Comment: That does not *delete* rows. It simply clears the contents of the cells, which is why the method is called `ClearContents`. To delete them, you want `Delete`.

Comment: If they are the bottom-most rows, try first `.Clear` instead of `.ClearContents`. If that doesn't work, then you'll have to use the less efficient `.Delete` as already suggested in the previous comments.

Comment: Thanks for the Answers. Sadly none of them worked. The empty rows still show up in the Word Document even if the cells in Excel have no content.

Comment: Try `.Range("A2:D" & .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp`. If that doesn't work then the problem lies in populating the rows in the first place i.e. you're probably copying blank rows at the bottom which you can only skip by using the `Find` method or looping through each row from the bottom. Either way, you should reveal more of your code.

Comment: Try `.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Copy`.